# How to get the value of an NSDecimalNumber from NSDecimal?

Tags: ios, nsdecimalnumber

I have an array of objects, each object has an NSDecimalNumber, call it "size"

For each object in the array, I will subtract a recommended size, called rSize.

I then want to go into the resultant NSDecimalNumber and get the value of the delta, don't really care if it's positive or negative result.

I think I'm going to use the decimalNumber method which will return a NSDecimal struct, so the question is: which property within the struct will give me the value of the delta?

To rephrase: A NSDecimal represents an NSDecimalNumber, but which property of the NSDecimal struct holds the value?

Many thanks
Rob

Comment: *All* of the fields in the `NSDecimal struct` hold "the value"; why aren't you using `-decimalNumberBySubtracting:`?

Comment: All the fields hold the value? Does isNegative hold the value? ;) Also I am using decimalNumberBySubtraction, but the result could be a negative value. I just want the size of the delta.

Comment: Yes, `isNegative` holds the *sign* part of the value (+/-). What do you mean by "delta"?

Comment: The size of the difference. So if I have an array of objects containing the sizes: 7,6,3,1 and the recommended size is 4. Then I will subtract 4 from each size, which will give: 3,2,-1 and -3. I don't really care whether it's plus or minus, I just want the delta, so 3,2,1,3.

Comment: I can then reorder the array of objects by delta, which will give 3,6,1,7. So the first object in the array will be closest to the recommended size, i.e. 3, and 6 will be the second closest size. I can use isNegative to tell whether it's bigger or smaller, but I need to know what property of the NSDecimal struct give the size of the NSDecimalNumber it's describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "delta" appears to be the absolute value of the difference between "rSize" and the item. In that case, you can perform the subtraction (`item – rSize`), and multiply it by -1 if it is negative entirely within `NSDecimalNumber`:

```
NSDecimalNumber *negativeOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1 
                                                                 exponent:0
                                                               isNegative:YES];
NSDecimalNumber *delta = [item decimalNumberBySubtracting:rSize];
if ([delta compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    delta = [delta decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:negativeOne];
}
```

Then use the `-compare:` selector on the resulting delta objects to sort your array of objects.

Comment: Yeah, that'll work. Thanks. Am I okay to set negOne as follows: `NSDecimalNumber negOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalWithString@"-1";`